# Android Studio cannot resolve symbols after cleaning gradle cache

Tags: android, android-studio

I deleted all the existing artifacts (artifacts and metadata) Gradle has downloaded using:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

My issue is that now Android Studio cannot resolve any symbols from my dependencies. Eg. `RecyclerView` shows up as red and I cannot view it's source.

Things I have tried unsuccessfully:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- restart Android Studio
- rebuild project
- Refresh All Gradle Projects.

I was able to fix the issue by creating a copy of the project, but this is not an acceptable solution. I use the command to clear the cache several times a day and cannot be constantly creating copies.

Comment: Did you previously enable `Offline Work` option?

Comment: No, it was not enabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Start Android Studio
2. Switch the file view from "Android" to "Project" view
3. Delete `.idea`
4. Delete `.gradle`
5. Delete all `*.iml` files
6. Files -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
7. "Invalidate and Restart"

Comment: This worked for me too. Gradle building worked perfectly, the app was being build and run without problems at all, but Android Studio kept complaining about that dependency even after using the infamous "Invalidate Cache / Restart" several times. This is actually reimporting the whole project to solve this glitch... I hope it doesn't happen too often.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by opening SDK Manager, clicking "Edit" under SDK Location, then completing the wizard. Nothing was updated, but the symbols were resolved.